# Sitecore Load all items into an MVC model?

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8

I have created a bunch of custom templates to store items (such as `Industries`, `Subindustries`, etc.) in Sitecore. I now want to go about loading these into my Sitecore MVC model.

---

The lists are located in *sitecore > Content > Lists*.   For example inside the *Lists* folder there is a folder called *Country*.   I want to get back all the items **within** the *Country* folder and populate them as unordered list in my view.

---

**UPDATE:** I implemented the *Glass.Mapper.Sc* method suggested below.   It is fully operational now.

This is what my working model looks like now:

```cs
using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration;
using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration.Attributes;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Sitecore.Web.Models
{
    public class Registration: IRenderingModel
    {
        public Rendering Rendering { get; set; }
        public Item Item { get; set; }
        public Item PageItem { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<CountryChildItem> CountryList { get; set; }

        [SitecoreType(AutoMap = true)]
        public class CountryItem
        {
            public virtual IEnumerable<CountryChildItem> Children { get; set; }
        }

        [SitecoreType(AutoMap = true)]
        public class CountryChildItem
        {
            [SitecoreId]
            public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

            [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Path)]
            public virtual string Path { get; set; }

            [SitecoreField]
            public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }

            [SitecoreField]
            public virtual string Abbreviation { get; set; }
        }

        public void Initialize(Rendering rendering)
        {
            Rendering = rendering;
            Item = rendering.Item;
            PageItem = PageContext.Current.Item;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is what my working contoller looks like:

```cs
using Glass.Mapper.Sc;
using Sitecore.Web.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Sitecore.Web.Controllers
{
    public class RegistrationController : Controller
    {
        Registration registrationModel = new Registration();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ISitecoreContext sitecoreContext = new SitecoreContext();
            ISitecoreService service = new SitecoreService(sitecoreContext.Database);
            Registration.CountryItem countryItem = service.GetItem<Registration.CountryItem>("/sitecore/content/Lists/Country");
            registrationModel.CountryList = countryItem.Children;
            return View(registrationModel);
        }
    }
}
```

and a snippet of my working view:

```
 <ul class="select-menu-options dropdown-menu">
    @foreach (var country in Model.CountryList)
    {
        <li><a href="#">@country.DisplayName</a></li>
    }
 </ul>
```

Comment: The question is very generic - maybe list what things you have tried already to get the data out? A lot will depend on the setup of your Sitecore content tree.

Comment: Added update with where the items are located in the tree.    As far as the "list of what you have tried", that is why I posted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were in your position I'd look into Glassmapper for Sitecore.

It's a fairly lightweight ORM for Sitecore.

http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc

I'd also suggest moving the lists located in

```
sitecore > Templates > User Defined > Lists > Content
```

to some where under either

```
sitecore > Content
```

or

```
sitecore > System
```

(whichever makes more sence)

UPDATE:
Try adding this above your class:

```
[SitecoreType(AutoMap =  true)]
public class CountryItem
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your `CountryItem` and other model classes to inherit from `SearchResultItem` like that:

```cs
[PredefinedQuery("TemplateID", ComparisonType.Equal, "{ID-OF-CountryItem-TEMPLATE}", typeof(ID))]
public class CountryItem : Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes.SearchResultItem
{
    [IndexField("_displayname")]
    public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [IndexField("abbreviation")]
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
}
```

You should be able to use Sitecore indexes to retrieve all the countries and other lists like that:

```cs
private static string IndexName
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format("sitecore_{0}_index", (Context.ContentDatabase ?? Context.Database).Name);
    }
}

private static string Language { get { return Context.Language.Name; } }

public IEnumerable<CountryItem> GetCountries() 
{
    using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(IndexName).CreateSearchContext())
    {
        IQueryable<CountryItem> queryable = context.GetQueryable<CountryItem>();
        queryable = queryable.Where(i => i.Language == Language);
        queryable = queryable.Where(i => i.LatestVersion);
        // ... maybe excluding standard values or some other filters
        var searchResults = queryable.GetResults();
        return queryable.ToList();
    }
}
```

Please be aware that this is just an example. You need to test it and most probably adapt to your solution.

And as Dar Brett mentioned, you should not keep any data items under the `Templates` node.

Comment: Moved the content items out and updated the question above.